# Como se valida en Laravel un campo decimal(11,2)?

Tags: php, laravel, validación

Hola amigos tengo un campo sueldo, como haría para validar desde la function rules()? ese campo en la base de datos lo tengo como un decimal(11,2).

```
'sueldo'=>'required|numeric|? como valido la longitud máxima?
```

De antemano les doy las gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usa una expresion regular:

```
'sueldo'=>'required|numeric|regex:/^[\d]{0,11}(\.[\d]{1,2})?$/
```

Esto acepta un numero entero de maximo 11 digitos con decimales opcionales 1 o 2 como maximo

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias, ya la marco como correcta